# Type System.UInt32 is not supported in Npgsql or your PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

With Npgsql V3.0.3.0 I am adding a new record to a table which has a column in the database with type OID, which should map to `UInt32` .Net type.

When executing the insert command the following exception is thrown "This .NET type is not supported in Npgsql or your PostgreSQL: System.UInt32".

The stack trace in the exception is:

```
at Npgsql.TypeHandlerRegistry.get_Item(Type type)
at Npgsql.TypeHandlerRegistry.get_Item(Object value)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ResolveHandler(TypeHandlerRegistry registry)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.Bind(TypeHandlerRegistry registry)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ValidateAndCreateMessages(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
```

The `GetSchemaTable` method from a `DataReader` on this table reports that the "Data Type" for the OID columns is `UInt32`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since OID is a somewhat internal/non-standard field, Npgsql won't automatically write UInt32 as OID; you need to explicitly say you want to write an OID by setting the parameter's `NpgsqlDbType` field to `Oid`.

Comment: The GetSchemaTable method of NpgsqlDataReader has a column called "ProviderSpecificDataType", but it is always null unless the "DataType" is "DateTime" (in which case it shows "NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDateTime"). Is it possible to update this method to return a "ProviderSpecificDataType" for every row. I am using this GetSchemaTable method in a T4 script to automatically generate a .Net class for each table, but without the "ProviderSpecificDataType" it is impossible to determine which fields are OIDs (to set the NpgsqlDbType).

Comment: @Casey, ProviderSpecificDataType is only for columns which support two CLR types - the "regular" type and the provider-specific one; DateTime is a good example because CLR DateTime can't represent the entire range of PostgreSQL timestamps. Just lookup ProviderType instead, of even better, call NpgsqlDataReader's GetFieldType() method.